# OpenJDK gives error: package org.jboss.weld.context.bound does not exist

Tags: maven, tomcat, java

I have a web app that compiles fine under Oracle's JDK 7, but gives the following error under OpenJDK 7:

```
error: package org.jboss.weld.context.bound does not exist
```

The error refers to a import in my code:

```java
import org.jboss.weld.context.bound.BoundRequestContext;
```

In my `pom.xml`, I have the following weld-related dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
  <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.8.Final</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
      <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>weld-servlet-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.8.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
  <artifactId>weld-se-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.8.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Is there any way to make it compile using OpenJDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not OpenJDK's fault.  You would most likely get the same problem with an Oracle badged JDK or a third-party Java compiler ... if you did an equivalent build with the respective compilers.

The problem is most likely caused by an incorrect Maven dependency.

According to [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/search?query=org.jboss.weld.context.bound.BoundRequestContext&n=), that class (`org.jboss.weld.context.bound.BoundRequestContext`) is defined in "weld-api", "weld-servlet", "weld-se" and "weld-osgi-bundle".  Try adding one of those as a dependency.

**UPDATE**

Judging from [this page](http://seamframework.org/Weld/WeldDistributionDownloads), "weld-api" is probably the way to go.  You might want to read it thoroughly to figure out the recommended set of dependencies.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. After messing with my environment, now I have the same error with Oracle's JDK.

Comment: It worked. I had to add weld-api and then cdi-api (because of another error). Why it was compiling before adding these dependencies is beyond my understanding.

Comment: In fact, my ultimate solution was to add weld-core (which depends on weld-api) and cdi-api. I guess my problem was caused by the fact that the parent pom declared weld dependencies with runtime scope, instead of compile scope, so that Eclipse downloaded them in my dev machine, but they were not available in my server machine.

Comment: Erm ... I recall having problems with compilation dependencies due to the Eclipse plugin adding stuff to the build path that was not warranted by the dependencies in the POM.  Workaround - do a command-line 'mvn' build regularly.  Sigh.